# How to identify a user authenticated with ADAL against ADFS 3.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, adal

I have ADAL for iOS working with an ADFS 3.0 server. It brings up a web view, the user authenticates and I get a call back with an access token.

The problem I have is that I get no information back about the user's identity. The `userInformation` property is `nil`. There's no `id_token` in any of the HTTP responses and I'm not sure how to request one in the first place. And I've seen elsewhere the Microsoft folks say that ADFS 3.0 doesn't support `id_token` at all. I've also parsed the JWT formatted access token and there's no information in there either that I can use to identify the user.

On the ADFS 3.0 server side, we have configured and enabled a Claim Rule that says to provide the relying party with GUID, Given Name, Surname, and Email Address. But adding that rule made no difference in the responses I get through ADAL.

How can I identify a user (i.e. get a GUID, first name, last name and email address) who was authenticated via ADAL against an ADFS 3.0 server? Is there an endpoint on the ADFS 3.0 server that I can hit with the provided access token where I can request this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that ADFS 3.0 may not support `id_token`, but if you have the Claim Rules for the Relying Party set correctly they will be added to the top level of the access token you receive. Apparently the claim rule should look something like this when it is correct:

[image: Claim Rule]

The access token is a JWT token so it can be decoded and the values retrieved from it there. When decoded, it will look something like this:

```
{
    "appid": "5f9a5589-6064-423a-8a1a-6a0d7ddda19f",
    "aud": "x-msauth-glazersapp://com.example.MyApp",
    "auth_time": "2016-08-08T22:32:14.459Z",
    "authmethod": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport",
    "email": "me@example.com",
    "exp": 1470699134,
    "family_name": "John",
    "given_name": "Doe",
    "iat": 1470695534,
    "iss": "http://adfs.example.com/adfs/services/trust",
    "objectGUID": "c8oMVOOEskutnPVno41Y1w==",
    "ver": "1.0",
}
```

"email", "family_name", "given_name" and "objectGUID" were added to the access token. And watch out, the GUID when provided like this is actually Base64 encoded.

More information available here: http://chrisrisner.com/Accessing-Resources-Secured-By-Azure-Active-Directory-with-iOS-and-Android

Comment: Cool. You have full id_token support in ADFS 2016. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-scenarios-for-developers for more info and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-fs/ad-fs-development for walk-throughs.

Comment: @David Hi David, have you used the ADAL library for communicating with ADFS server ? What is the portal url where we have to register our application and get the client id ?

Comment: @subin272 I have used the iOS ADAL library before but it has been a few years. If I recall correctly, this has to be configured via the Active Directory control panel within Windows itself. I don't believe there is a portal URL equivalent to that.